# azure setting variables across subscription contexts

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to powershell script (Az latest) an existing vnet peering configuration using `add-azvirtualnetworkpeering`.  The two vnets are in different subscriptions.  It appears I must use a variable for the `virtualnetwork` and `remotenetwork` switches.  I can set my subscription context for 1 and apply `get-azvirtualnetwork` assigning it to `$vnet1`, then switch context to the other subscription context and assign the second `$vnet2` value.  But when I run the `add-azvirtualnetworkpeering` command (from either subscription context) it gives me *A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter 'virtualnetwork' or 'remotenetwork'* depending on which context I am in.  See example 2 here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azvirtualnetworkpeering?view=azps-1.6.0 except the RG is already created and I use a `get-azvirtualnetwork` in place of the `new-azvirtualnetwork` since they already exist.  Code looks like this:

```
PS C:\>set-azcontext (get-azsubscription -subscriptionname "1")
PS C:\>$vnet1 = get-azvirtualnetwork -name "vnet1"
PS C:\>set-azcontext (get-azsubscription -subscriptionname "2")
PS C:\>$vnet2 = get-azvirtualnetwork -name "vnet2"
PS C:\>add-azvirtualnetworkpeering -name "vnet1tovnet2" -virtualnetwork $vnet1 -remotenetwork $vnet2.id -AllowForwardedTraffic
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Add-AzVirtualNetworkPeering : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'remotenetwork'.
> At line:1 char:99
> + ... vnet1tovnet2" -virtualnetwork $vnetfrom -remotenetwork $vnet2 ...
> +                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-AzVirtualNetworkPeering], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.AddAzureVirtualNetworkPeeringCommand
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vNets are in the same tenant then using set-azcontext is overkill, just use select-azsubscription to change the subscription you are working with, and this won't touch any of your variables.

However, your parameters are also wrong. Check the documentation for [add-azvirtualnetworkpeering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azvirtualnetworkpeering?view=azps-1.6.0) the parameters are VirtualNetwork and **RemoteVirtualNetworkId**